# Hidden Phrase Within Rant

Tags: cipher, word-sequence

Foreword: This is a puzzle. I wouldn’t read too much into it… unless it applies to you. Below is not what you might expect from a puzzle. There are no misspelled words, no hidden Morse Codes, no translated numbers. Essentially its perfect. Okay, it might not be perfect but that was the intent.

> Although it is your prerogative whether to withhold judgment, or else harass posters on their poor puzzles, please take the occasion to not embarrass yourself or start unnecessary arguments, and instead show acknowledgment that posters have given commitment to this community with indispensable entertainment. Accommodate their attempts, even if the consensus is that the existence of their puzzle is an inadvertent duplicate, or that their riddles are dependent upon information not privileged to readers. Perseverance is necessary, and even with the occurrence of bad posts, anyone can eventually improve. By all means proceed with voting them down, but you do not have license to insult other members. There are times when it is necessary to keep personal opinions separate from what you write.

Well with that rant over, here’s the important part.

> •◘ ♦☺ ♪♥ §☺ ☺♦ ►♥ ☼♠ ♥♥ ◙♀ ¶♦ ♀○ ↕♦ ♂♥ ◘♥ ◄♦

HINT:

> There is a direct correlation between the symbol pairs and specific words in the above "rant".

Comment: In my edits I left out a pretty important part of the puzzle from the forward.. I've added it back in.

Comment: "forward": how ironic.

Comment: haha, woops. Foreword.

Comment: (I should say that although I've noticed the Obvious Thing, it's still far from clear to me how to use it to solve the puzzle.)

Comment: And what are we supposed to make of the fact that the foreword contains two *punctuation* eros — I mean errors?

Comment: Ok, I broke the symbols out into pairs, which is important.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "rant" is full of

> infamously often-misspelled words.

Here's a list of

> such words therein, in order of appearance, each preceded by an attempt to indicate what error is commonest, represented by a wrong letter and its correction. It's not always obvious whether a word should be considered commonly-misspelled; OP has given me a bunch of hints towards the set they had in mind, and perhaps I've more or less got it now.

So:

> `- r` prerogative [NOTE: this might be "whether" instead; doesn't make any difference which we choose]
>  `- h` withhold
>  `e -` judgment
>  `r -` harass
>  `s -` occasion
>  `- r` embarrass
>  `- e` argument
>  `- w` acknowledgement
>  `t -` commitment
>  `i a` indispensable
>  `- m` accommodate
>  `c s` consensus
>  `a e` existence
>  `a e` inadvertent
>  `a e` dependent
>  `e i` privileged
>  `e a` perseverance
>  `- r` occurrence
>  `? ?` proceed
>  `c s` license
>  `e a` separate

Now let's take a look at those weird characters.

> They are all from the earliest region of the old IBM "code page 437" as found on old PCs. If I've got 'em right, their character codes are: 7 8 4 1 13 3 21 1 1 4 16 3 15 6 3 3 10 12 20 4 12 9 18 4 11 3 8 3 17 4. (The second could have been 2 rather than 8, but it turns out that 8 works and 2 doesn't.) Notice that they fall into pairs where the *second* number in each pair is rather small, and in particular is no greater than the number of letters in the commonly-misspelled word whose position is given by the *first* number.

Doing the obvious thing we get

> THISRIDDLESUCKS,

and the conclusion we are clearly intended to reach is that

> THIS RIDDLE SUCKS.

*Note*: There was a lot of to-ing and fro-ing before reaching the analysis above, whose traces those with sufficient privileges can see in the edit history and everyone can see in the comments below. Thanks to OP for being patient with my fumblings.

Comment: You are extremely close, however some of the words you've selected are not supposed to be there (3 of them to be exact) and there are 3 others you missed. Find those 6 and you're about done. 21 words in total.

Comment: And kudo's on the codes.

Comment: OK, I removed (a guess at) the 3 least plausible words on my list and added (a guess at) three runners-up. Right now I'm none the wiser as to what to do with them, but maybe inspiration will strike :-).

Comment: I would go back and not remove any of your words. Perhaps focus on adding possible new ones, and then going from there. There should be enough information at that point in order to find what you're looking for.

Comment: To make it a little less mind-numbing, the words "Necessary" and "Unnecessary" are not on my list.

Comment: Been a few days @GarethMcCaughan, you need a hint to finish it up?

Comment: It's beginning to look sadly as if I do :-).

Comment: You've already identified the symbols to numbers, and you've isolated specific words. Try working with just those alone.

Comment: Oh, duh, that's a thing I should have thought of for sure. I think my list of words is still not the same as yours, but that's probably fixable. (Not right now, though; it's ~2.30am local time and I need to go to bed.)

Comment: Indeed there are only 15 pairs of symbols and 21 words. You are absolutely on the right track with the "SUCKS" part, but you have a few words on your list that don't belong. That's why some of your initial letters don't make sense. Only 3 of your first 5 words are on the list, and Judgment is one of them.

Comment: I just noticed one more issue. You're missing a word between embarrass and acknowledgement.

Comment: Cor, I'd completely forgotten about this one...

Comment: OK, got it now, though I can't seem to make the first letter work.

Comment: Change unnecessary to argument. Somehow this is on the list of most frequently misspelled words.. maybe "arguement"?

Comment: Oh! I confess it never occurred to me for a moment that that one might be difficult, but of course you're right.